# Ref count issue in Allocations instrument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, instruments

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhsnm9u16gscsm8/Allocations%20instrument.png

Check this link..
In the Allocations instrument under the reference count column, there is an entry after autorelease and release entries where the reference count becomes 3(the selected entry).. I don't understand how the ref count went up to 3 from 1 since ref count increases or decreases by 1 at each step. This doesn't seem right. I have even checked the code using stack trace.. I just don't get it. I'm a first time user of Instruments app and Allocations instrument.. The rest of the allocation/deallocation entries above the selected one are clear to me.. The selected entry is where the problem starts. Am i interpreting this the wrong way or what? Pls assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `#` column on the left side. Because the list is displayed "By Group", some of the events are displayed out of order.
Change to "By Time" and you should see something like that:

```
#25 | Retain      | 2
#26 | Autorelease |
#27 | Retain      | 3
```